# YouTube IFrame Player API and video metadata

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I would like to get metadata about the current video. The video is ready to provide the data using player.getVideoData() but the author is empty.

player.getVideoData() returns

`Object {video_id: "pXvGbOThFwc", author: "", title: "ZARA Woman Campaign. Spring Summer 2015"}`

If I look at the player object itself the metadata is available in player.B.videoData as

`videoData: Object
  author: "zara"
  title: "ZARA Woman Campaign. Spring Summer 2015"
  video_id: "pXvGbOThFwc"`

I'm only able to find limited info about the video metadata in the api docs or google. The result is the same across multiple browsers.

Is the another way to be the author or more metadata using the IFrame Player API?

#### Did some extra tests:

It seems the author is somehow added later. player.B.videoData.author is also empty when I call player.getVideoData().

The docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getDuration) state that player.getDuration() will be 0 until the video metadata is loaded. player.getDuration() is not 0 at the time I call player.getVideoData() so the metadata should be loaded.

Calling player.getVideoData() a few seconds later will provide a none empty author.